# Need Fix for NetworkManager Openvpn, prepending extra-path to crt-path

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn, nmcli

When adding a openvpn ovpn-file through the network GUI (and `nmcli` too), and trying to connect, it fails.
But it works if I manual are connection with `openvpn` through the terminal.

After a look in the `journalctl -u NetworkManager` it turned out the it is prepending: `/var/lib/openvpn/chroot/` to the link to the `crt-verify.pem`-file.

```
nm-openvpn[9582]: Options error: --crl-verify fails with '/var/lib/openvpn/chroot//home/notroot/.cert/nm-openvpn/othernetwork-crl-verify.pem': No such file or directory (errno=2)
```

With a search for a solution, I found out I was not the only one with that problem:

[[Bug 1835644] [NEW] CRL files are not accessible for the Verify CRL options](https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5613321.html)

[Debian Bug report logs - #903240](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=903240)

But I was not able to find a config-file for the given vpn-setting, or any other way to fix this.

Are there anyone that have a workaround/fix for this?

Running:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- nmcli tool, version 1.22.10
- OpenVPN 2.4.7

Answer (score 0):

After a looking around, I found that the config-file for Network Manager could be found at: `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/othernetwork.nmconnection`
But it turned out that the patch was correct in the config-file. So a bug-report should be send to: [Free Desktop gitlab for MN](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager)

For whomever there can make a login (or have one).

An Work-around will be to make a softlink, in the patch`/var/lib/openvpn/chroot`, to the home folder.
The Command will be:`sudo ln -s /home /var/lib/openvpn/chroot/home`

For more info about `ln`: [ln man-page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html)